# C++: temperature converter - why calculation return 0

Tags: c++

Why is k value returns 0?  Please help.

```
double fah, kel;

fah = std::atof(input.c_str());  //convert string input to a double & assign value to be fah degree 
kel = (double)((f + 459.67) * (5/9)); //calculate fah temp to kelvin
```

k value returns 0 when I add "5/9" to the calculation.

Answer (score 4):

In C++, `5/9 == 0` because of integer division.

Use `5.0/9`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is integer division. The result of this:

```
5/9
```

is `0`. You should use a floating point type:

```
5/9.0 // 9.0 is a double.
```

Comment: Why is only one of those two number needs to be in a decimal form?

Comment: @user2925557 it is enough for one of the operands of the division operator `/` to be a floating point (FP) type for the operation to be calculated in FP (and the result of the operation to be FP)

Comment: @user2925557 an operation of `int/double` or `double/int` is automatically promoted to a `double` result.  For readability, it is often good to write both as a double - though, that is not required.

Answer (score 0):

Expression 5 / 9 has integral type that is its result is equal to 0.
Change (5/9) at least to (5.0/9)

Answer (score 0):

This is an integer division issue.  Additionally, you simplify the equation a bit:

```
Dk = C*Df + C*B ===> Dk = C*Df + A
```

where `Dk` is degrees Kelvin, `Df` is degrees Farenheit, `C` is the `5/9` constant, and `A` is `C*Kelvin Offset` (also constant).  Which would make your code:

```
const double FtoKMultiplier = 5.0/9.0; // done at compile time
const double FtoKOffset = 459.67 * FtoKMultiplier; // also done at compile time
double fah = std::atof(input.c_str());
double kel = FtoKMultipler * fah + FtoKOffset; // single multiplication and addition at runtime
```